# Global Variables and DarkMode

Tags: android, android-activity, boolean, global-variables, android-application-class

I am trying to make a `Global Variable` to make a dark mode for my entire `app`. But it seems that its not working.

I already followed the guide to make a `Global Variable`.
Here is what I have so far:

```
    GolobalVariables appState;
    appState = ((GolobalVariables) this.getApplication());
```

And this is my `on touch event` that works:

```
   @Override
 public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
      mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        darkMode();
                    appState.setDarkModeOn(!appState.isDarkModeOn());

                    }
                });
            }
```

Here is the `darkMode method`:

```
private void darkMode() {

    Log.d("DarkMode", "`" + appState.isDarkModeOn());

    if(appState.isDarkModeOn()) {
        maarivRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
        for (int i = 0; i < maarivLinearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            ((TextView) maarivLinearLayout.getChildAt(i)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        }
    } else {
        maarivRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        for (int i = 0; i < maarivLinearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            ((TextView) maarivLinearLayout.getChildAt(i)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
        }
    }


}
```

I change the state of the `boolean` so that when switching activities the variable stays the same. Only when the user long presses on the screen, does it switch.

2 problems occur:

1. It the boolean doesnt keep its state throughout the app.
2. When closing and reopening the same activity, the Log statment would say false at opening and false again when long pressing. true and true.

   Here is my manifest

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   ```

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   ```

   ```
   <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>

   <activity android:name=".Davening"/>
   <activity android:name=".Benching"/>
   <activity android:name=".Zmanim"/>
   <activity android:name=".Extras"></activity>
   <activity android:name=".Shacharis"></activity>
   <activity android:name=".Mincha"></activity>
   <activity android:name=".Maariv"></activity>
   <activity android:name=".Compass"></activity>
   <activity android:name=".TestingZone"></activity>




   <!--Camera-->
   <activity android:name=".CameraView"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait">
       <!-- configure this activity to use landscape orientation -->
   </activity>



   <!--<application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />-->
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>




   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" /><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
   ```

   App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->

And here is my Golbal Variables Class:

```
    package com.example.edonfreiner.siddur;

    import android.app.Application;

    public class GolobalVariables extends Application{
    public boolean darkModeOn = false;

    public boolean isDarkModeOn() {
        return darkModeOn;
    }

    public void setDarkModeOn(boolean darkModeOn) {
        this.darkModeOn = darkModeOn;
    }
    }
```